# Checking if multidimensional ArrayList has a value multiple times

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, iteration

I have a multidimensional ArrayList of variable size (in the example I will assume it contains 3 ArrayLists).
These ArrayLists contain Team objects that look like this: Remco & Joris.
I am only allowed to have a combination once, so Joris & Remco would also count as a duplicate.

I know how to see if 2 arraylists contain the same value but how would I go about doing this in a multidimensional arraylist of variable size?

As an example, my arraylist looks like so:

```
[
[Hidde & Lege plaats, Hans & Sven, Martijn & Simon, Remco & Joris, Daniël & Wouter, Jelle & Aziz, Dylan & Jasper, Mart & Ramon, Tim & Job, Jan & Brian, Thomas & Robin, Kevin & a, Zeger & Chariss, Wilfred & Bart],
[Hidde & Bart, Hans & Lege plaats, Martijn & Sven, Remco & Simon, Daniël & Joris, Jelle & Wouter, Dylan & Aziz, Mart & Jasper, Tim & Ramon, Jan & Job, Thomas & Brian, Kevin & Robin, Zeger & a, Wilfred & Chariss],
[Hidde & Chariss, Hans & Bart, Martijn & Lege plaats, Remco & Sven, Daniël & Simon, Jelle & Joris, Dylan & Wouter, Mart & Aziz, Tim & Jasper, Jan & Ramon, Thomas & Job, Kevin & Brian, Zeger & Robin, Wilfred & a]
]
```

I put in some linebreaks to make it look better. In the program it's just 1 single line.

Comment: Doesn't actually exist. The names can be changed in a file, but I'll edit my question to use names like those in the example.

Comment: I think the only option available is to just check for every value if there is another one in the entire array. Since they are all supposed to be different you cannot avoid looking at each one separately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this

// Assuming `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> multiDimenArr` has values, and `HashTable` for checking the occurrence of values/items

1) 2 nested for loops to traverse `multiDimenArr`.

2) for each value in `multiDimenArr` ... check if `Hashtable` already has it by is `contains(Object value)`

3) if it is already present // do what ever you want

4) else put the `value` in the `Hashtable`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your data structure is this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> matrix = new ArrayList<>()
```

Your team objects though seem to be well defined and would benefit from *not* being a string... so when you parse them in, parse them a s a real object.

```
public class Team {
   Set<String> teamMembers = new HashSet()

   public boolean equals( Object o  ) {
     return ( o instanceof Team && Team.class.cast(o).teamMembers.equals(this.teamMembers) )
   }
}
```

Then regardless of how your made your team, teams consisting of the same members match as true.

NOTE: I'm leaving *a lot* of things out for brevity.

Alternately, you could really simplify your base data structure to just be

```
Set<Set<String>> matrixOfUniqueCells = new HashSet<>()
```

which would enforce unique teams of unique members.

Answer (score 0):

Let me restate your question as 'how do I test if two lists of lists intersect according to a customised definition of equality'. Please correct me in comments if I've misunderstood.

A neat way to do this in Java 8 is to flatten both through streams and use of `flatMap`:

```
boolean hasCommonItem(List<List<String>> list1, List<List<String>> list2) {
    return list1.stream().flatMap(List::stream)
        .anyMatch(team1 -> list2.stream().flatMap(List::stream)
            .anyMatch(team2 -> teamEquals(team1, team2)));
}
```

You would then implements a `teamEquals` method that compares the strings for teams. In your case that could be something like:

```
private boolean teamEquals(Stream team1, String team2) {
    return members(team1).equals(members(team2));
}

private List<String> members(String team) {
    return Arrays.stream(team.split("&"))
        .map(String::trim)
        .sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

It'd be a lot more efficient to create the teams as lists of members first and make your structures lists of lists of lists of members.